# Vlookup for differente sheets Excel

Tags: excel

Good afternoon,

> I am trying to use a VLOOKUP formula across different sheets, but so
>   far I am unsucessful.
>
> The formula I am using is the one below:
>
> ```
> VLOOKUP(R9;INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(ListaFolhas;MATCH(1;--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&ListaFolhas&"'!$C$4:$D$4");R9)>0);0))&"'!$C$4:$D$4");2;FALSE)
> ```
>
> ListaFolhas is the name of the range of the names from the different
>   sheets.
>
> [image: Cell where I am trying to insert the formula]
>
> Basically I need to insert the number associated with each person:
>
> [image: Number associated with each person]
>
> What can I be doing wrong? I used this formula from a page and adapted
>   to my own case...

EDIT:

After some research I figured out an answer. However, I am facing a new problem: The formula I found only considers one word, doesn't consider 2+ words. A screenshot of the situation:

[image: Problem using Indirect function with two words]

In the image I have the formula I am using and the difference I get. Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX(range of cells with the numbers, MATCH(name you are looking for,ListaFolhas, 0))

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately it did not work. I already figured it out but I am still having some issues. Could you please see my EDIT? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ListaFolhas seems to only contain the first name.